# How to solve $u_{tt}=\Delta u-(x_1^2+4x_2^2)u$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation, partial-functions

Find a nontrivial solution of $$u_{tt}=\Delta u-(x_1^2+4x_2^2)u$$ for $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, $t>0$ such that $u_t$ is a nonzero function and $|u(x,t)|\leq C$ for $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, $t>0$, where $C$ is a positve constant.

I’m trying to extend the method from Evan’s book for nonlinear first-order PDE,
$$F(D^2u,u,x)=u_{tt}-\Delta u+(x_1^2+4x_2^2)u=0$$
Then $F(p,z,x)=b(x)p+c(x)z$, here $b(x)=(1,-1,-1)$, $c(x)=(x_1^2+4x_2^2)$ and so
$$D_pF=b(x).$$
$$\dot{x}(s)=b(x(s)),$$
$$\dot{z}(s)=b(x(s))\cdot p(s)=-c(x(s))z(s)$$
For here we have $$\dot{x}^1=-1,\dot{x}^2=1,\dot{x}^3=1.$$

Edit: From the comment, I know that this is a linear problem not nonlinear. Thus, the method not work. While I try to separate it but I fail.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: That PDE is linear.

Comment: As it stands at the moment, this is a linear pde. I’d suggest you see what standard separation of variables leads to.

Comment: It’s also a second order PDE not first order, so the method of chracteristics doesn’t apply

Comment: Oh, I see why it can't work. But I still stuck to solve it, I try separation of variables but I don't know how to separation while it has a variable $t$ not only $x.$ I rewrite it as $$u_{tt}-u_{x_1x_1}-u_{x_2x_2}+(x_1^2+4x_2^2)u=0.$$ But how to separate?

Comment: @A rural reader I still stuck to solve this problem. Do any can give more hint? or detail thoughts, thanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are in fact dealing with a linear PDE and you are just looking for *any* nontrivial solution, seperation of variables should be your first try:

$$
u=T(t)X(x_1)Y(x_2)\\
\Rightarrow T''XY=TX''Y+TXY''-(x_1^2+4x_2^2)TXY\\
\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
\frac{X''}{X}-x_1^2=\lambda\\
\frac{Y''}{Y}-4x_2^2=\mu\\
\frac{T''}{T}=\lambda+\mu
\end{cases}
$$
solving these equations for arbitrary $\lambda,\mu$ involves the parabolic cylinder function.
$$
X(x_1) = c_1 D_{-\frac{\lambda+1}{2}}(\sqrt{2} x_1) + c_2 D_{\frac{\lambda-1}{2}}( \sqrt{2}i x_1)\\
Y(x_2) = c_3 D_{-\frac{\lambda+2}{4}}(2 x_2) + c_4 D_{\frac{\lambda-2}{4}}(2i x_2)
$$
with potentially complex $c_i$. Now somebody with deep knowledge of parabolic cylinder functions would be able to determine for which choices of $\lambda,\mu$ there exists constants $c_i$ such that the resulting function is nontrivial, real and remains bounded.

However since you are only looking for one (!) solution we can make our lives easier by observing that $D_0(x)=e^{-x^2/4}$.

Therefore the special choice of $\lambda=-1,\mu=-2$ allows for a solution in terms of "standard" functions, namely

$$
X=e^{-x_1^2/2}\\
Y=e^{-x_2^2}\\
T=A\cos(\sqrt{3}t)+B\sin(\sqrt{3}t)
$$

Please note that this is only one very specific class of solutions.

Comment: Why you choice $\lambda$ and $\mu$ like that? Is you choice arbitrary, then after choice we need to check the condition  from question for here is bounded and $u_t$ nonzero function, right?

Comment: So for here solution are not unique since many possible pair of $(\lambda,\mu)$ can met the condition here. The choice you choose is a solution here.

Comment: I added some additional lines, hopefully its more clear now.